# How to remove a Word.Selection?

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, vsto, add-in

In the context of an Outlook add-on using the WordEditor from the Outlook.Inspector I would like to remove the selection after replacing it with a custom text.

For example, if I select something I can change the selection to a custom text as follows:

```
Word.Selection sel = doc.Windows[1].Selection;
Word.Range range = sel.Range;

    if(sel.Text.Length == 0) {
        MessageBox.Show("No Text is selected");

        return;
    }

sel.Text = "New Text";
sel.Collapse();
```

If I call this function again, now sel.Text.Length is equal to 1 instead of 0.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar, but is `doc.Windows[1].Selection` only readable or assignable too? It may make sense to re-assign it after you're done your edits.

Comment: Only readable/getter: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.window.selection.aspx

Comment: Seems like comparing if sel.Range.Start == sel.Range.End does the trick?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem in MS Word. Word has a method called Selection.Move(). If you use it it will deselect the selected text and place the cursor at the end of the selected text. For example you can use

```
ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Move()
```

This works in a Word add in if you want to deselect selected text, it may work in Outlook too, try and let me know

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work in Outlook the selection length remains in 1.

Answer (score 3):

You might wish to try

```
Selection.Collapse Direction := wdCollapseStart
```

This will set the start and end positions of the current selection to the same value, namely the start of the current selection (specify `wdCollapseEnd` instead for the end of the current selection). The result should be programmatically indistinguishable from actually deleting a selection.

hope this helps, carsten

applies to: word 2007 (tested), word 2010; possibly other releases

Comment: In .net it is msWord.Selection.Collapse(Direction:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart)